# Safari alternative to gleebox for mouseless navigation?

Tags: macos, safari

When I switch to Safari from Chrome I really miss the mouseless navigation plugin that highlights every link and input with a letter ("A", "B"... "AA", "AB"...) and typing that combination + Enter follows the link.

I've found out [gleebox](http://thegleebox.com), that seems to be a multibrowser alternative, but it is not as fast and most of all the project seems abandoned.

Can you suggest a good way to navigate the web without using a mouse with Safari? Thanks

Comment: Gleebox is awesome.

Comment: Gleebox is nice, but not that handy. Or I just got badly accostumed to numbers or letters, like Mouseless Browsing on Firefox. My main case are unread icons for fora navigation. Even with Gleebox, they're not so handily accessible. Until I find out how, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Type to Navigate](http://dbergey.github.com/) extension, it allows you to jump to links by typing a portion of their text.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nice one, but still no way to easily access images with the same ALT attribute. :-(